# HandlebarsJS each only prints last item in array

Tags: javascript, mustache, handlebars.js

This is a branch off from this question: [Handlebars.JS (w/ Dashbars) parse error "expecting open_endblock got inverse"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29754153/handlebars-js-w-dashbars-parse-error-expecting-open-endblock-got-inverse/) (There's also a codepen therein.)  I posted this there because I thought the problems were related, maybe (since `{{else}}` can be used with if's or each's,) but that turned out not to be the case.

Specifically:

> I'm also having the problem of my outermost `{{#each}}` looping in such a way that only the last record returned is being output through the template. Everything logs in `{{log this}}` after that opening `{{#each}}`, but it's not even hiding in the HTML output somewhere.

So my table SHOULD have 4 rows, and objects 0 through 3 log to the console, but only the fourth item, item 3, is added to the table.  Inner each's work as expected, as do any and all other iterator functions; I'm not sure why it's JUST the outer one that's failing.  The JSON from which my array of objects is created validates in every single linter I've used, as does my JavaScript.  Atom is supposed to have a handlebars linter, but it doesn't seem to actually...umm...work.

I AM using [Dashbars](https://github.com/pismute/dashbars) with this, (with both its [lodash.js](http://lodash.com) and [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) dependencies,) but this bug has existed since before I started using that library.  FWIW, jQuery 2.1.3 IS installed, and loaded before any other library, and all of that is in the `<head>` tag.  (I don't see where it would matter, but just in case.)  And since JavaScript is involved, yes, I'm in Chrome.  The version of Handlebars is the latest, 3.0.1, using the full version because my use-case doesn't allow pre-compiling.  Another NB is that all of this is embedded in a .cfm file (not my choice,) so everything does get run through the CFML interpreter first.

Comment: Does the last item not match the conditional whereas the others do?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP It's not a conditional, it's just, essentially, a for-each.  The only way the `{{else}}` condition on an each should fire is if you pass it an empty array.

Comment: I meant this: `#if (s-start-with? 'Y' PRIMARY_FLAG)`

Comment: @SmokeyPHP I'm not being clear.  The outermost each tag takes an array of objects from JavaScript, and each object has objects and arrays in IT, and I can iterate over anything WITHIN one returned record, just fine.  That last record is parsed without any problem, displays as it should.

Answer (score 0):

So...I'd managed to outsmart myself again. I've created a [fork](http://codepen.io/Muzical84/pen/EjxWex?editors=101) of my original code, but HTTPS policy in my browser is keeping it from working =-\

The "money" differences are as follows (can't use SO's `<ul>` because I can't embed code in a bullet-block)

*I'd been trying to jam my template into a `<tr>` element, to avoid having Handlebars process more lines of code than I thought was necessary:

```
 <tr class="searchResults" id="searchResultsHTML"></tr>
    <script id="result-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <!--- To accommodate for that this would all begin and end with a <tr>, I tried this:  --->
         {{#unless @first}}
                <tr>
            {{/unless}}
            <!--- The rest of the template --->
           {{#unless @last}}
                </tr>
            {{/unless}}
    </script>
```

*In good-programmer fashion, I'd forked my actual file several times, trying different things.  (Mostly did this to avoid endless git resetting and branching; I know git's meant for this sort of thing, but I just wanted to be able to refresh old and new tabs at once.  Anyway!)  Took out those `{{unless}}` blocks and...apparently, I'd misunderstood what that does (since [the official documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html) is a bit...scant...on that point.  There's no TRUE inverse of `{{#if}}`)  For the sake of those who don't want to bother clicking to the codepen:

```
<div class="searchResults" id="searchResultsHTML">
<script id="result-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <table id="resultTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Personal Information</th>
            <th>Education</th>
        </tr>
        <!--- The log tag DOES output all records, even the ones that aren't showing in the HTML. --->
        {{#each this}} {{log @index}} {{log this}}
        <tr>
                    <td>{{#with basicInformation}}
                        <p>{{MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID}}&nbsp;({{CUSTOMER_STATUS_CODE}})<br />
                        {{SEARCH_NAME}}<br />
                        (<span class="lightBlue">ADD:{{ADDOPER}}&ndash;{{{d-format 'MM/DD/YYYY' (d-date 'YYYY-MM-DD' ADDDATE)}}}</span>)</p>

                        <p>DOB:{{{d-format 'MM/DD/YYYY' (d-date 'YYYY-MM-DD' BIRTH_DATE)}}}<br />
                 {{/with}}</td>

           <!--- More table columns; six total --->

            <td>{{#each education}}
                        <p>{{INSTITUTION_NAME}}&nbsp;({{{d-format 'YYYY' (d-date 'YYYY-MM-DD' BEGIN_DATE)}}}&ndash;{{{d-format 'YYYY' (d-date 'YYYY-MM-DD' END_DATE)}}})</p>
                    {{else}}
                        <p>No education records found</p>
                    {{/each}}
                </td>
        </tr>
        {{else}}
            <tr class="alert largerError" id="errorMessageRow">
            <td class="empty" id="errorMessage" colspan="6">Either there has been an error, or your search did not return any records from any datasource.</td>
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
</script>
```

Yes, I stuck with ColdFusion comments; since those are ONLY for my reference, or the poor next developer, they don't need to go to the client and that way Handlebars isn't taking valuable time rendering them.  (I'm already annoyed Handlebars is going to have to churn through my header row and a bunch of other text.)  This tool searches our databases for customer numbers that MIGHT represent accidental duplicate accounts, so if you search for John Smith...oi!

So for anyone who Googled their way over here...I'll be glad if this helps even one person avoid spinning their wheels the way I did.